# Running Drush on the server

Tags: drush

I want to run Drush on a OpenSuse Linux Version 12.1 box 32-bit machine.
I have a server admininistrator that takes care for the backend.

What do I need to ask him, in order to get Drush running on the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run Drush, you need ssh access to the server.  This means you need your sysadmin to make an account in the server for you.

To run the "pm-" commands, and a few others, this account will need to have both read and write access to the DOCROOT.  There are a few ways to do this; let your admin pick which is best for your setup.

You will also need PHP available from the command line, preferably with the same php.ini that the website uses.

Comment: hello dear MPD - let me sume up if you got right: i need an ssh access. BTW i allready can access to the server with FileZilla and WinSCP with SSH2 Way. **Question:** With regard to  that ways i allready use to access the server i have the question: do i allready have the necessary prerequesites here...!?  What do you mean - i  eagerly want to know if i have the prerequesites for **DRUSH[ed] access** to the SERVER allready... The PHP-Availability from the commandline. - well this i have to ask for!? MPD i look forward to hear from you again - many greetings

Comment: You *may* have SSH access if WinSCP works, but your admin  will be the person to tell you and you don't want to be SSHing in unless they give the go-ahead.  Yes, making sure PHP works from the CLI (and is properly configured) should be the only other thing you need.

Comment: hello dear MPD - thx for the clear words. I talk to my Sysadmin to get all things done. Many many greetings - yours

Answer (score -2):

[Drush](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install/) should be installed as a dependency of [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/), so first install Composer:

```
sudo zypper install php-composer
```

Then use Composer to install the Drush 8.x version:

```
composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

To register Drush as a dependency of Composer:

```
composer require drush/drush
```

To integrate Drush with the Bash CLI utility:

```
drush init
```

OpenSuse Direct Install Packages:

- [Drush on OpenSuse](https://software.opensuse.org/package/drush)
- [Composer on OpenSuse](https://software.opensuse.org/package/php-composer)